# pandas datetime format conversion

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

My dataset has values in date column as in following format:

```
date
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
[datetime.date(2017, 2, 17)]
```

I want to convert them into datatype of datetime so that I cant perform time series analysis over it.

i have written in following way: but its giving me value error

```
df_scores['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_scores['date'],format='[datetime.date("%Y, %m, %d")]')
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df_scores['date'].str[0])`?

Comment: Is it a column of datetime lists? Or is it a column of strings?

Comment: column of strings. which i want to convert into datetime format.

Comment: I've given you an answer that caters to both requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is a column of `date` objects in a list, this should suffice -

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df_scores['date'].str[0], errors='coerce')
```

If you have a column of strings, you could use `str.findall` to extract the date artifacts, and `str.join` to join them in a format that `to_datetime` understands.

```
i = df.date.astype(str)\
      .str.findall('\d+')\
      .str.join('/')
df.date = pd.to_datetime(i, errors='coerce')
```

The `astype(str)` is required if you have a column of *list of strings*, rather than a column of strings. You may also need another parameter `errors='coerce'` if you have malformed data in your column.

---

```
df

         date
0  2017-02-17
1  2017-02-17
2  2017-02-17
3  2017-02-17
4  2017-02-17
5  2017-02-17
6  2017-02-17
7  2017-02-17
8  2017-02-17
9  2017-02-17
10 2017-02-17
11 2017-02-17
```

Comment: Resulting dataframe has date of type "non-null datetime64[ns]".
why it says non-null ? when it should be just datatime64

Comment: @MayurMahajan So, that means it worked... unless you have some other problem? To my knowledge, there isn't any difference.

Comment: I dont understand why it says non-null datetime64[ns].

Comment: @MayurMahajan That probably means there are no nulls in the column, I suppose? I'm not sure, and I don't think it's a problem. Unless you're getting an incorrect result?

Answer (score 0):

if you `from datetime import datetime`
then you should specify dates like this:
`[datetime(2017, 2, 17)]`
This will result in entries of type `<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>` which you can convert to datetime using `.to_datetime()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
df_scores['date']=pd.to_datetime(df_scores['date'],format="[datetime.date(%Y, %m, %d)]")
```

Comment: ValueError: time data '[datetime.date(2013, 7, 31), datetime.date(2013, 8, 1)]' does not match format '[datetime.date(%Y, %m, %d)]' (match)

Comment: So a single row in your dataframe can have two or more date values?

Comment: No DF doesnt have 2 or more data values.